# store to null pointer of type 'char'

Tags: c

I get the problem when I solved the problem 3 on leetcode.I write the code and it works on `Dev-C++` compiler,and I copy the code and paste on the leetcode.Get this error:`Line 10: Char 9: runtime error: store to null pointer of type 'char' (solution.c)`.I checked the code, but can't find some problems.I wish get some help.The code is paste on the below.

```
int lengthOfLongestSubstring(char * s){
    int longestlength = 0;  // 最长子串的长度 
    int i = 0;
    char *temp; // 存储子串 
    char *p;
    char *base;

    * temp = * s; // *temp存储s的第一个字符 
    base = temp;

    while(*++s != '\0') {
        p = base;
        while(*p++ != '\0') {
            if (*p == *s) {
                *temp = '\0';
                break;
            }
        }
        if (*temp == '\0') {
            *temp++ = *s;
            base = temp;
            i = 0;  // 重新计数 
        }
        else {
            *++temp = *s;
            ++i;
        } 
        longestlength = i > longestlength ? i : longestlength;
    } 

    return longestlength;
}
```

Test Example

```
char* s = "pwwkew";
```

Comment: It's right there. `*temp = *s`. But `temp` isn't initialized, so you can't possibly do `*temp`. Are you trying to copy the string pointed to by `s`?

Comment: No, I want to use the first of the string potinted to by `s` initialized the temp.

Comment: If `temp` is supposed to point to a temporary buffer or string, then you must allocate space for it. Until you do so,`temp` is a [wild pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer), which will likely cause run-time errors if you dereference it.

Comment: @Eli OP needs to define `char temp;`, too, for this to be correct. But then `base = temp;` will be wrong...

Comment: Please make a [mre] and identify line 10 with a commnet `// this is line 10`. I am however with hobbs, that surly is the culprit line.

Comment: Could you provide an URL to the problem in leetcode site ? It is difficult to understand what you are trying to do by reading your code. `*temp = *s` is definitely an error, but there might be more.

Comment: For instance, another error is `*++s != ’\0’`. If `s` is an empty string, this test won't detect it and happily read data beyond the end of the string. Why modifying `s` ?

Comment: The URL to the leet code is [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/). The function must return the length of the longest substring without repeating characters.

Answer (score 1):

The function is the proposed solution to the problem suggested by leetcode [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/).

As I understand it, we have to return the length of the longest substring without repeating character. A substring ends when the after last character appears at any place in the substring.

There are many problems with the presented code.

- The error is because there is no storage for `temp`.
- `base` is a copy of `temp` which is not a terminated string, but it is scanned with pointer `p`.
- `i` is incremented in certain conditions, but never reset to zero. When a new substring is started, it should be reset to 0.
- etc.

I don't see how this code can provide the expected answer.

The algorithm is as follow.

we start with a substring whose first letter is at index `i` (initialized to 0), and we consider the after last character of the substring at index `j`. We check if the character is present in the substring. if yes, we met the end of the substring. It's length is `j-i`. `longestLength` is then set to the max of longestLength and `j-i`. We start a new substring by setting `i` to the letter after the duplicate letter in the substring. Finally, we increment `j`.

Here is the code

```c
int lengthOfLongestSubstring(char *s){
    if (s == NULL || *s == '\0')
        return 0;
    int longestlength = 1;
    int i = 0, j = 1;
    while (s[j] != '\0') {
        // check if s[j] is in substring
        int k = i;
        while (k < j) {
            if(s[k] == s[j])
                break;
            k++;
        }
        // if we found a duplicate letter at index k
        if (k != j) {
            // we reached the end of the substring
            longestLength = j-i > longestLength ? j-i : longestLength;
            // next substring start at k+1
            // and is one character long
            i = k+1;
            j = i;
        }
        j++;
    }
    return longestLength;
}
```

Comment: I know your answer is right.But I still want to know how to correct errors and how to solved the problem.I will post a question with my new code.I wish get your help.Thank you.

Comment: You loseed the situation  that `k == j`, I added the situation:`longestLength = j - i + 1 > longestLength ? j - i +1 : longestLength;`.Then I posted the anwser,it's passed.

Comment: @John.W that's strange because I submitted my answer as it is to leetcode and it passed all tests and was accepted.

Comment: That's too strange.I submitted answer that use your code and leetcode rejected.However, the problem I meeted is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I modified my code to correct the errors that you pointed.

```
int lengthOfLongestSubstring(char * s){
    int longestlength = 0;  // 最长子串的长度 
    int i = 1;
    char *temp; // 存储子串 
    char *p;
    char *base;
    int nowsize = 0;

    temp = (char *)malloc(2*sizeof(char)); 

    *temp = *s; // *temp存储s的第一个字符 
    *(temp+1) = '\0';
    base = temp;
    nowsize = 2;
    longestlength = i;

    while(*++s != '\0') {
        p = base;
        while(*p != '\0') {
            if (*p == *s) {
//              *temp = '\0';   
                break;
            }
            p++;
        }
        if (*p != '\0') {
            free(base);
            base = (char *)malloc(2*sizeof(char));
            temp = base;
            *temp = *s;
            *(temp+1) = '\0'; 
            i = 1;  // 重新计数
            nowsize = 2; 
        }
        else {
            base = (char *) realloc(base, (++nowsize)*sizeof(char));
            temp = base + nowsize - 2;
            *temp = *s;
            *(temp+1) = '\0';
            temp++;
            ++i;        
        }   
        longestlength = i > longestlength ? i : longestlength;
    } 

    return longestlength;
}
```

I explain some varaibles in my program, `temp` pointed the longest unrepeated substring, and `base` pointed the base address, and `p` is for traverse.`i` is incremented  only the character in `s` not repeated in `temp`.

The program run my well with the test example that the `problem3` provided.But when I posted, I get the errors.`AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000331 at pc 0x0000004018ab bp 0x7fff4145b010 sp 0x7f`.I try my best and can't 
simulate the situation.I wish get some help,thank you!

Comment: Temp has room for 2 characters, but some substrings in the test cases are longer. I would suggest to give it the length of s because a substring can never be longer than s. Use `strlen` to get the length of s. There is no need to multiply by `sizeof(char)` because it is 1. The type cast in front of `malloc` is also not necessary. Use `temp = malloc(strlen(s)). You should also handle the case when s is an empty string and return 0. This will save you from problems. For instance, the return value of `malloc(0)` is undefined. It can be NULL or a block with 0 bytes. If it's NULL your code crash.

Comment: I use `realloc` allocate memory when the character is not repeated in the base.The position(`base + nowsize - 2`) is pointed the '\0' before and pointed the character that is not repeated in the base.Then the position(`temp+1`) pointed the '\0',why may storage overflow?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `realloc`. Note that `*(temp+1) = '\0'` should be written as `temp[1] = '\0'` because it is more readable. Always use a more readable form. You still have a problem if `s` is an empty string. The instruction `*++s == '\0'` won’t properly handle empty string. I tested your code for various input and I didn’t see a problem. Do you have the test string that cause this error ?

Comment: The only problem I see is if `s` is an empty string. You should add the instruction `if (*s == '\0') return 0;` in the beginning of your program.

Comment: Your program doesn’t give the correct response with string "abcdebhijklmn". It returns 8 and it should be 11. This is because once you found a duplicate character (b), you reset the substring to the duplicate letter (b). You must reset the substring to the first letter after the duplicate character (c). You must thus move `s` backward. Adding the instruction `while (s[-1] != *p) s--;` just before the `free(base)` instruction, solves the problem.

Comment: Another comment is that you don’t need the variable `temp`. You can write `base[nowsize-2] = *s; base[nowsize-1] = '\0';` after you `malloc` or `realloc` base.

Comment: A final comment, copying the substring in `base` is useless. You can avoid the `malloc` and `realloc` and the backtracking of `s` by simply using the index of the first letter of the substring in `s`. You also shouldn’t modify the pointer `s`. I used `i` as the index of the start of the substring, and `j` as the index of the after last character of the substring. We test if the character `s[j]` is in the substring from `i` to `j-1`. The length of the substring is `j-i`. This is much simpler and achieves the same result.

Comment: Here is a link about `problem3`.[problem3](https://leetcode-cn.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/).I think the correct response with string "abcdebhijklmn" is 8, because `acdehijklmn` is a subsequence and not a substring.

Comment: I tested the code for various input and I didn't see a problem too.It just reported erros when I submit the code on leetcode.Maybe some situation I don't take into consideration.

Comment: the longest substring without repeating characters in "abcdebhijklmn"  is "cdebhijklmn" and it is 11 characters long. I know about this particular case because I made the same error as you in my first implementation. leetcode rejected my answer. The problem could result from the incorrect handling of the empty string s. It won’t be detected if there is another byte 0 somewhere after s. If there are none, the program will reach the end of the heap.

Comment: Yes,you are right.I try add the situation handle then post the answer, and leetcode rejected my answer.Thank  you.I know the problem is . I misunderstand the means of `problem3`.I will modified my program.